# Can a boost::lockfree::queue be checked for full?

Tags: c++, boost, queue, lock-free

I am using a boost::lockfree::queue Foo(128).

Before Popping the queue I can check the queue for empty status by `Foo.empty()` function.

I was wondering if I can check similarly for its status at full capacity before Pushing! Couldn't find any resource online explaining how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears Boost's LF multi-producer multi-consumer `queue` implementation doesn't support this.  Other MPMC queues might.

[`boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html#id-1_3_23_6_4_1_1_1_13_15-bb) (single-producer single-consumer ring-buffer queue) does, with `spsc.write_available() > 0`.

---

[`boost::lockfree::queue` is not fixed-size by default](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html), only if you pass a capacity as a template arg, or `fixed_sized<true>`.  *If the data structure is configured as fixed-sized, the internal nodes are stored inside an array and they are addressed by array indexing.*  (But it's not a ring-buffer like some other MPMC queues.)  Otherwise they're dynamically allocated and kept on a free-list.

For performance you probably *should* make it fixed-size.  Or if you want to limit dynamic allocation, you can use `bounded_push` instead of `push`, so it will return false instead of going to the OS for more memory (which might not be lock-free).

---

If you are using a `queue<fixed_size<true>>`, then it *is* possible for the queue to become full.

But It wouldn't be very meaningful to check separately because **another producer could have made the queue full between the check and the push**.  Are you looking for a performance optimization like avoiding constructing the object if the queue would probably still be full by the time you're ready to call `push`?

(Also, a consumer could make the queue non-full right after you check, so it really only makes sense to check as part of an attempted push.  And perhaps there isn't even an efficient lock-free way to check.  Otherwise they could have had the function always return true for non-fixed-size queues, and return a meaningful result for fixed-size.)

**This is why `push()` returns `bool`: `false` means the queue was full** (or a new node couldn't be allocated for non-fixed-size queues).

---

> Before Popping the queue I can check the queue for empty status by `Foo.empty()` function.

I hope you're not actually doing this; it has all the same problems of racing with other threads as `push`, and with fewer opportunities to optimize.  There's no object to construct before the attempt, you just call `pop` and see if you get one or not.

Another thread could have made the queue empty, or made it non-empty, between your check and your actual pop.  Unless you're the only consumer, in which case seeing non-empty does mean you can definitely pop.  A multi-producer single-consumer use-case would not be compatible with `spsc_queue`.

Anyway, this is why it's `bool pop(T &);` not `T pop()`.

Comment: That was a nicely drafted answer. Thanks :)